# derivative of a projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, derivatives

The projection onto a parametrised vector $v(\lambda)$ is $P_v = \frac{vv^{T}}{v^{T}v}.$ Its complement is $$P = I-\frac{vv^T}{v^{T}v}.$$ I've got an expression containing this complementary projection and I need its derivative. How do I calculate

$$\frac{\partial P(v(\lambda))}{\partial \lambda} \text{ ?}$$

I started with $$\cfrac{\partial P(v(\lambda))}{\partial \lambda} = \cfrac{\partial P(v(\lambda))}{\partial v} \cfrac{\partial v(\lambda))}{\partial \lambda}$$ where only the expression $\cfrac{\partial vv^{T}}{\partial v}$ I can't handle. How can I find this derivative of a matrix with respect to a vector, or the original derivative with respect to the scalar parameter $\lambda$?

Comment: I think it is simpler to compute the derivative in coordinates. Since $vv^T=[v_iv_j]$ one differentiates with respect to $\lambda$ and finds $\partial_\lambda P = v' v^T + v(v')^T$.

Comment: (It may also help to remember that transposition commutes with differentiation.)

Comment: Which makes it: $$\frac{\partial P(v(\lambda))}{\partial \lambda} = - \frac{(v^{T}v)(v'v^{T}+v(v')^{T}) -vv^{T} ((v')^{T}v+v^{T}v') }{||v||^{4}} $$, correct?

Comment: @mike Giuseppe's answer is correct.  I'm not sure what your comment is all about

Comment: @mike oh! You're applying the quotient rule to your normalized version.  Yes, you did so correctly.  Note that what you've written only makes sense if you treat $v^Tv$ as a scalar (in other words, the matrices are not conformable if you regroup that product).

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering about that. This is, becuse matrix notation is not well suited for differentials, right? Or can I somehow circumvent this inconsistency?
Also Guiseppe Please put your Comment into an answer, such that this does not stay "open".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Giuseppe Negro I found the answer to be:

$$\frac{\partial P(v(\lambda))}{\partial \lambda} = - \frac{(v^{T}v)(v'v^{T}+v(v')^{T}) -vv^{T} ((v')^{T}v+v^{T}v') }{||v||^{4}}$$

after using the quotient rule. Remark: I used the general case here, where $v$ is not necessarily of unit length, so it needs to be normalised by its norm.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply to clear the fraction
$$\eqalign{
(v^Tv)\,P
  &= (v^Tv)\,I - (vv^T) \cr
}$$
Differentiate (using $d=\frac{d}{d\lambda}$ for ease of typing)
$$\eqalign{
d(v^Tv)\,P + (v^Tv)\,dP
  &= d(v^Tv)\,I - d(vv^T) \cr
(dv^T\,v+v^Tdv)\,P + (v^Tv)\,dP
  &= (dv^T\,v+v^Tdv)\,I - (dv\,v^T+v\,dv^T) \cr
(v^Tv)\,dP
  &= (dv^T\,v+v^Tdv)\,(I-P) - (dv\,v^T+v\,dv^T) \cr
}$$
Solve for $dP$
$$\eqalign{
dP
  &= \frac{(dv^T\,v+v^Tdv)\,(I-P) - (dv\,v^T+v\,dv^T)}{v^Tv} \cr
  &= \frac{(dv^T\,v+v^Tdv)\,(vv^T) - (v^Tv)(dv\,v^T+v\,dv^T)}{(v^Tv)^2} \cr
}$$